# Streamlit add remove widgets dynamically

Tags: streamlit

I have this program that just creates `selectbox` on the left `pane` in `streamlit`. I can't figure out how when I click on the remove selectbox `button`, to make the `selectbox` widget in the left pane go away:

```py
import streamlit as st

def main():
    st.title("Selectbox Addition and Removal")

    num_selectboxes = st.sidebar.number_input('Number of Selectboxes', value=1, min_value=1, max_value=10)

    selectbox_containers = []

    for i in range(num_selectboxes):
        container = st.sidebar.container()
        selectbox_label = container.text_input(f"Label {i + 1}", f"Option {i + 1}")
        remove_button = container.button(f"Remove Selectbox {i + 1}")
        selectbox_containers.append((container, remove_button))

    if st.button("Apply Changes"):
        for container, remove_button in selectbox_containers:
            if remove_button:
                container.empty()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: The logic is not clear. Could you add more details on what you wanna do?

Comment: It's much easier to state in english than show code. I want to be able to dynamically add and remove st.sidebar.container(). !!!

Comment: Do you wanna save them between streamlit runs in a [session state](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/session-state) or just change the total number of containers?

Comment: Just add and remove them. I don't need to save them.

Comment: You're adding and removing containers by +/- in `number_input`. Why do you need then additional buttons for the same purpose?